# Use Alt-letter symbols on KDE

Tags: arch-linux, kde, keyboard, plasma

I've just installed KDE Plasma using Antergos, and I am quite annoyed at the default behavior of the alt-keys, since pressing altGr-2 does not type out the at key, but rather the same command as alt-2. Is there any way to revert this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your keyboard model, layout, or options isn't set correctly. In KDE, there is a "Keyboard" settings panel where you can change it. Easiest way to pull it up is to open the KDE menu or the quick-runner, and start typing "Keyboard".

You can also get to it under KDE Menu→Computer→System Settings→Input Devices.

It looks like this: 
[image: KDE keyboard settings].

Many of these can also be set system-wide. E.g., on Debian it'd be `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but I'm not sure about Antergos.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have set tried setting it to both the generic one and the Asus laptop one, however the alt-key still only works as a shortcut for some reason. I am running Arch(installed with Antergos + KDE selected) and it refuses to work for me; all alt-keys(i.e. vertical bar as well) do not work.

Comment: @AlbertSjlundVliro Check under advanced, key to chose 3rd level—maybe you need to pick something like right alt. Also make sure you have the correct layout selected (under the Layouts tab).

Comment: Thank you @derobert, that was it. While it is not an inconvenience as I use the different alt-keys different, can you use the alt-key both as 3rd-level and as a shortcut? I.e. alt+2 gives at-sign and alt-tab gives the application switcher.
Also, I've noticed that panel settings do not save after relog(i.e. the position of system tray, they reset to the leftmost position after reboot). Is this the correct behaviour?

Comment: @AlbertSjlundVliro the easiest way to do that is probably to assing AltGr-tab as an alternate keyboard shortcut to that. You can do that in the "Global Shortcuts" settings panel (inside Shortcuts), look under the KWin shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you for your time @derobert . It was driving me crazy!